# If $e$ is idempotent and both $eRe$ and $(1-e)R(1-e)$ are orthogonally finite, is $R$ orthogonally finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$ possessing a non-zero idempotent $e$. It usually happens that if $eRe$ and $(1-e)R(1-e)$ have a property $P$ then so does $R$.

A ring is said to be [**orthogonally finite**](https://books.google.com/books?id=rDbABAAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=%22orthogonally+finite%22+definition&source=bl&ots=Yjx0MEVf1Z&sig=TOBb7f04mumkRGGM_132fe0_xaQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ3b_JgrvKAhWFWh4KHcidBTQQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22orthogonally%20finite%22%20definition&f=false) if it contains no infinite set of nonzero orthogonal idempotents.  I want to know whether $R$ is orthogonally finite if  $eRe$ and $(1-e)R(1-e)$ are both orthogonally finite.

Thanks for any cooperation!

Comment: Hi: I took the liberty to attach the standard name to that property you described, and I also made your title more useful. I hope the changes suit you. It is an interesting question which I haven't approached before. What properties do you know work? I think it is a little surprising given the freedom of what can happen in $eR(1-e)$ and $(1-e)Re$.

Comment: For example, if both $eRe$ and $(1-e)R(1-e)$ are semiperfect rings then so is $R$ because $e, 1-e$ are orthogonal idempotents summing to $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counterexample occurring in nature (for some rather generous definition of "nature") comes from the fact that there are abelian groups $A$ that have direct sum decompositions both as a direct sum $B\oplus C$ of two indecomposable groups, and as the direct sum of infinitely many non-zero groups. If $R$ is the endomorphism ring of such a group $A$, and $e$ is projection onto $B$, then $R$ is a counterexample.

The existence of such groups was proved in the (one-and-a-half page) paper: A. L. S. Corner (1969). *A note on rank and direct decompositions of torsion-free Abelian groups. II.* Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, 66, pp 239-240. and can also be found in Fuchs' book(s) on *Abelian Groups*.)

A more contrived but "generic" example is the ring
$$R=\mathbb{Z}\langle e,e_1,e_2,\dots\vert e^2=e, e_i^2=e_i, e_ie_j=0 (i\neq j)\rangle.$$
It's not hard to show that $R$ has a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis consisting of the words in $e$ and the $e_i$ that alternate $e$s and $e_i$s (such as $e$, $e_1$, $ee_2e$, $e_1ee_2e$), including the empty word as the multiplicative identity, and that $eRe$ is the free ring generated by $\{ee_ie\vert i=1,2,\dots\}$, with multiplicative identity $e$, which has no idempotents other than $0$ and $e$. Similarly $(1-e)R(1-e)$ has no idempotents other than $0$ and $1-e$, but of course $R$ has the infinite set $\{e_1,e_2,\dots\}$ of orthogonal idempotents.

Comment: That's a good strategy, and I hope to see the example of $B\oplus C$, because that is pretty weird...

Comment: @rschwieb I've added a reference.

Comment: With regards to the "more direct" approach, it is probably necessary to specify some relations between $e$ and the $e_i$, right? I can't see immediately what to do to make both corners orthogonal finite though.

Comment: @rschwieb I'd be willing to bet that even without any more relations, the corners have no non-obvious idempotents: can you see any? :) I make no claims about how easy it would be to prove, though.

Comment: Maybe... I was just suspicious that the $e_i$ would somehow descend to idempotents in the corners. If all the $e$'s commuted this would happen, but maybe in the free algebra it is really not an issue..

Comment: @rschwieb Actually, maybe it's not too hard. I haven't checked carefully, but I think $eRe$ is just a free ring on generators $ee_ie$.